# How to Insert : semicolon while doing re in Python

Tags: python, regex, numbers

In this program i want to display only numbers and semicolon excluding ' and ]

But my output shows only number not semicolon. 
How to get a output with both semicolon and numbers

```
code
=====
import re

a = "'23:33:26]"
a = re.sub('[^0-9]','',a)
print(a)

My output 
==========
233326

Needed Output
=============
23:33:26
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `:` to your regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

a = "'23:33:26]"
a = re.sub('[^0-9:]','',a)
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
23:33:26
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the expression like this, It will work

```
a = re.sub('[^:0-9]','',a)
```

Expression replaces with `''` other than `0-9` and `:`. You were not included `:` in the expression.